# Gmail is not showing new messages as unread

Tags: gmail

Gmail is not showing my new messages as unread. Is there some setting or preference that has been changed?

I'm viewing Gmail in my web browser, Firefox 13.01, Mac OSX 10.7.

Other browsers have the same issue, as does Apple Mail.

Answer (score 1):

Try with first disabling Ad-block. Or with

- Open `Adblock preferences` from `Tools`
- Adblock Plus Preferences `[Ctrl-Shift-O]` and make sure your Filter
  Subscriptions are up to date.

And to resolve the issue for Apple Mail go to email account settings and change your user name to `@gmail.com`.

Hope this helps.